# Save the state of my RadioGroup when have a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I'm having some problems when implementing a listview with RadioGroup. 
When i select some CheckButton of my RadioGroup and after i scroll the listview, my ChechButton is unchecked. I'm trying to fix it, but i dont know how to do.
I know that i need to save the state of my checkbutton and load it when my listview is created. But i don't know how to do it.

Does anybody can help me with my code?

Here have the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="8dp"
android:id="@+id/teste"
android:background="@drawable/borderframe"
tools:context="com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.layoutListaAMC">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/potencial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Potencial"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/potencialLetra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/azulgerdau"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/potencial"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/questao" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/potencial"
        android:text="As máquinas e equipamentos possuem selo de liberação por um líder Gerdau e está dentro do prazo de validade?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Condiçao Fisica"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/questao"
    android:layout_below="@+id/potencialLetra" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/questao">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupAmc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/sim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sim"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/nao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sim"
            android:text="Não" />

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/na"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NA"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nao"
        />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

And here we have the apater:

```
class AdapterAmcPersonalizada extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal;
    private final Activity act;


    public AdapterAmcPersonalizada(List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal, Activity act) {
        this.mensal = mensal;
        this.act = act;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mensal.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mensal.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_layout_lista_amc, parent, false);
        AvaliacaoMensal mensalAmc = mensal.get(position);



        //pegando as referências das Views
        TextView potencial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.potencialLetra);
        TextView questao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questao);
        TextView titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);

        //populando as Views
        potencial.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getPotencial()));
        questao.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getQuestao()));
        titulo.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getTitulo()));


       RadioGroup radioGroupAmc = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAmc);
       radioGroupAmc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.sim:

                            // trata radioValor1
                            break;
                    case R.id.nao:

                            // trata radioValor2
                            break;
                    case R.id.na:

                        // trata radioValor3
                        break;
                }

            }
        });



        return view;
    }



}
```

Here i have my List whith data:

```
 public List<AvaliacaoMensal> todosMensal() {
        List<AvaliacaoMensal> dados = new ArrayList<AvaliacaoMensal>();
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As máquinas e equipamentos possuem selo de liberação por um líder Gerdau e está dentro do prazo de validade?", 'A', "Condição Fisica", false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Atividades se encontram sinalizadas ou isoladas?", 'B' , "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Todos os colaboradores estão usando os EPI´s básicos, específicos e em boas condições? Os EPI's são adequados aos riscos das atividades? Quando aplicável são realizados pré-uso dos mesmos?", 'B', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As plataformas, andaimes, enlonadores, estruturas de guarda corpo e corrimão se encontram em boas condições?", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Máquinas e equipamentos que possuem partes rotativas estão adequadas conforme NR 12?", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Existe local adequado para refeição e sanitários suficientes conforme NR 31?", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A contratada faz o uso de bloqueio de energia quando aplicavel?", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Todas as maquinas devem possuir proteção contra tombamento e cinto de segurança", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A frente de trabalho possui caixa de primeiros socorros?", 'C', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Está sendo cumprida a proibição de utilizar adornos como: brincos, pulseiras, relógios, cordões, anéis, etc?", 'C', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As proteções contra quedas, seja para acesso ou execução das tarefas, estão instaladas e usadas  de acordo c/ os procedimentos de segurança e conforme projeto elaborado por profissional habilitado ?", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Os veículos operacionais e transporte de pessoas passaram pela vistoria mensal?", 'A', "Condição Fisica",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Todas atividades realizadas possuem padrão, IO ou APR?", 'A', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A APR é de conhecimento, está assinada por todos os executantes da tarefa e disponível na frente de serviço?  Toda liderança da contratada foi treinada nos padrões de APR e PT?", 'A', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As IPU's estão sendo preenchidas corretamente para máquinas, equipamentos, veículos e ferramentas manuais?", 'A', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Colaboradores que executam atividades críticas estão portando crachá de autorização para Riscos Críticos?", 'A', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Operadores e motoristas estão portanto CNH?", 'C', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A empresa tem uma média de 2 relatos por colaborador?", 'C', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A empresa está emitindo RTR?", 'C', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Os relatos estão sendo tratados em DDS?", 'C', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A empresa está dando fedback dos relatos e RTR para colaboradores?", 'C', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Está sendo realizado aferição de pressão arterial para colaboradores que realizam atividades críticas?", 'C', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Possui alguma ação em atraso de acidente?", 'A', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Regras Gerais e específicas estão sendo cumpridas?", 'B', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Possui novos colaborares na area? Se sim, possuem padrinhos treinando em ordem de serviço, IO, padrão e etc?", 'A', "Sistema",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A contratada deve possuir a coleta seletiva implantada e recipientes identificados à disposição dos colaboradores", 'B', "Meio Ambiente",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A coleta seletiva deve ser utilizada corretamente, com a destinação correta nos recipientes", 'C', "Meio Ambiente",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As embalagens de produtos quimicos / agrotóxicos devem ser devidamente armazenadas e devolvidas ao fabricante", 'A', "Meio Ambiente",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("A contratada destina corretamente o óleo lubrificante usado e toma medidas adicionais durante o abastecimento de maquinas / motosserra", 'B', "Meio Ambiente",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As instalações devem ser localizadas com geografia favorável para obtenção de água, fora das APP (áreas de preservação permanente), com distância mínima a 100 metros dos rios e das nascentes d’água.", 'A', "Meio Ambiente",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Os produtos Químicos e Combustiveis estão armazenados de forma correta?", 'B', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Deve ter FISQP de todos os produtos armazenados, com atendimento as remendações e regras de armazenamento.", 'B', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Os locais de armazenamento possuem placas de acesso restrito e cadeado?", 'B', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As embalagens vazias de combustíveis ou lubrificantes devem permanecer neste local até ser retiradas da fazenda.", 'B', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Os produtos quimicos e inflamaveis são acima de 37°? Se não, existe autorização da area de SSMA da unidade?", 'A', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("O deposito de produtos químicos posuem sinalização e proteção contra incêndios?", 'A', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Os serviços com produtos químicos e inflamáveis, possui a APR e Permissão de Trabalho? ", 'A', "Produto Quimíco e  Combustiveis",false, false,false));

        // Continuação do código
        return dados;
    }
```

And here i have my class AvaliacaoMensal:

```
class AvaliacaoMensal {
    private String questao;
    private char potencial;
    private String titulo;
     private boolean sim, nao, na;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store radio groups values into the `AvaliacaoMensal` object. Otherwise whenever user scrolls the view radiobuttons filled by another view's values which is unchecked.

```
public class AvaliacaoMensal{
     boolean[] radioButtonValues = new boolean[3];
    ....
}
```

**UNTESTED!**

```
 class AdapterAmcPersonalizada extends BaseAdapter {
        private AvailacaoMensal flag;
        private final List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal;
        private final Activity act;


        public AdapterAmcPersonalizada(List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal, Activity act) {
            this.mensal = mensal;
            this.act = act;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mensal.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mensal.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_layout_lista_amc, parent, false);
            AvaliacaoMensal mensalAmc = mensal.get(position);



            //pegando as referências das Views
            TextView potencial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.potencialLetra);
            TextView questao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questao);
            TextView titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);

            //populando as Views
            potencial.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getPotencial()));
            questao.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getQuestao()));
            titulo.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getTitulo()));


           RadioGroup radioGroupAmc = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAmc);

           flag = mensalAmc;
           radioGroupAmc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                    switch(checkedId) {

                        case R.id.sim:
                                flag.radioButtonValues[0] = group.isChecked();
                                // trata radioValor1
                                break;
                        case R.id.nao:

                                // trata radioValor2
                                break;
                        case R.id.na:

                            // trata radioValor3
                            break;
                    }

                }
            });



            return view;
        }



    }
```

Create a flag inside the adapter to select which is the current Object. Because if you access the position inside the `onCheckedListener`, position needs to be final.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't add a `boolean[] radioButtonValues = new boolean[3];` into my my `AvaliacaoMensal`, because if i do these i need to change my List with data. I put these into my question.

Comment: I do not understand why you can not add this but you could create another arraylist inside the baseadapter which is the same size with your objects, and store your radio button values into it. But this is a bad practice and might occur some problems

Comment: isChecked its not working. Say that Cannot Resolve Method isChecked.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you `getView` method you should set state of your `RadioGroup`, radioGroupAmc in this case. And `onCheckedChanged` you should remember your choice to restore it later in `getView`. In your case convinient to store this information in `List<AvaliacaoMensal> mensal`.